# JaxB Unmarshaller Error

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshal a basic XML file using JaxB however there is something wrong with the code. The marshaller runs correctly however the unmarshaller, instead of returning what's in the XML file, returns  `com.project.test.Jaxb@094jufd34c`. (The name of the class followed by an '@' with a random combination of letters and numbers). Here is the code below. Thanks for any help or ideas.

XML Annotated Class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Jaxb {
String newString;

public String getNewString() {
    return newString;
}

@XmlElement
public void setNewString(String newString) {
    this.newString = newString;
}
}
```

Marshaller:

```
public class Marshal {
Jaxb newWindow = new Jaxb();
String xmlString;

void marshal(String[] args) {

    xmlString="a,b,c";

    newWindow.setNewString(xmlString);

 try {

        File file = new File("newXml.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Jaxb.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(newWindow, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(newWindow, System.out);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
}
```

Unmarshaller:

```
public class unmarshal {

static String unMarshal() {
  String unmarshString="";
  try {

        File x = new File("newXml.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Jaxb.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Jaxb newUnmarshal = (Jaxb) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(x);

        unmarshString = newUnmarshal.toString();

      } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print("error");
      }
  return unmarshString;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.project.test.Jaxb@094jufd34c` is the output of the default `toString()` implementation on your `Jaxb` class. Override `toString` to output whetever you need it to output, e.g.

```
public String toString() {
    return newString;
}
```

However, I'm guessing that since your `unmarshal` method specifically returns a String, then what you really want to do is just `unmarshString = newUnmarshal.getNewString()` instead of `unmarshString = unmarshal.toString()`

> The name of the class followed by an '@' with a random combination of letters and numbers

It's not random, it's defined by the [javadoc for `Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.
>
> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

This has nothing to do with XML or JAXB, this is just how to define `toString` on a class.